# How to use WLResourceRequest in worklight 8.0 android

Tags: java, android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm new to worklight, currently working on hybrid android project and following worklight 8.0 documentation.

For Java adapters, use `/adapters/{AdapterName}/{path}`. 
The path depends on how you defined your `@Path` annotations in your Java code. This would also include any `@PathParam` you used.

My questions are,
1. What is the path?
2. I did't find @Path annotation?

Can anyone guide me to how to use WLResourceRequest in android.

```
//Here I'm using javascript adapters
    URI adapterPath = new URI("/adapters/adapter name/procedure name");
        WLResourceRequest request = new WLResourceRequest(adapterPath, WLResourceRequest.POST);
                    request.setHeaders(getHeaders());
        request.setTimeout(30000);
                    request.send(jSONString, wlResponseListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Path annotations in your Java code : It is being referred to JAVA Adapter code.

For example, if you have adapter code like below:

```
package com.sample.adapter;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/")
public class JavaAdapterResource {

  //Define logger (Standard java.util.Logger)
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaAdapterResource.class.getName());

 //Path for method: "<server address>/Adapters/adapters/JavaAdapter/{username}"
    @GET
    @Path("/{username}")
    public String helloUser(@PathParam("username") String name){
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

@Path("/") before the class definition determines the root path of this resource. If you have multiple resource classes, you should set each resource a different path.

For example, if you have a UserResource with @Path("/users") to manage users of a blog, that resource is accessible via http(s)://host:port/ProjectName/adapters/AdapterName/users/.

That same adapter may contain another resource PostResource with @Path("/posts") to manage posts of a blog. It is accessible via the http(s)://host:port/ProjectName/adapters/AdapterName/posts/ URL.

In the example above, because there it has only one resource class, it is set to @Path("/") so that it is accessible via http(s)://host:port/Adapters/adapters/JavaAdapter/.

Each method is preceded by one or more JAX-RS 2.0 annotations, for example an annotation of type “HTTP request” such as @GET, @PUT, @POST, @DELETE, or @HEAD. Such annotations define how the method can be accessed.

Another example is @Path("/{username}"), which defines the path to access this procedure (in addition to the resource-level path). As you can see, this path can include a variable part. This variable is then used as a parameter of the method, as defined @PathParam("username") String name

Take a look at the below links for more details

i.[Resource request from JavaScript (Cordova, Web) applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/)

ii.[Creating JAVA Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/#implementing-a-jax-rs-20-resource)

iii.[ResourceRequestCordova sample app](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/ResourceRequestCordova/blob/release80/www/js/index.js)

iv.[Sample Adapter code](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/Adapters/blob/release80/JavaAdapter/src/main/java/com/sample/adapter/JavaAdapterResource.java)

Comment: Kallnnavar I have followed ur steps and able send the request to server (using javascript adapter). It is working fine without any parameters but when send request with parameters I always getting 500 error. please have look i have added code.

Comment: You will have to Set  content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded or use resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams); instead request.send

Read more about this here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/#sendformparamtersjson